# I am trying to find vowels then add them, but did i do this right?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Idk if I did this right.. I just want to know how to add the vowels together to make three because my name is Daniel 3 total vowels but its not working when I add other names.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Pratclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner std= new Scanner(System.in);
        String string1;
        System.out.println("What is your name");
        string1= std.nextLine();

        int count= 0;
        int vowels=0;

        for(String retval: string1.split(""))
        {
            for(int i=0; i < retval.length(); i++)
            {
                char c= retval.charAt(i); 
                if(c== 'a' || c== 'e' || c== 'i' || c== 'o'|| c== 'u') 
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println(retval.substring(0,1) + retval.substring(1) + vowels);
                vowels=0;
                }
        }
        int total=vowels++;

        total=(total + vowels++ + vowels);      < How can I count the vowels 
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(total);

    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to input, for example, `Daniel Mark Cataline`?

Comment: "But it's not working" - What is it doing? What should it be doing?

Comment: 'How can I count the vowels'? Isn't that what you created `int vowels = 0` for?

Comment: what does that mean int vowel=0 ? it can't because i set the vowels it to zero? @ trobbins?

Comment: also can someone explain to me what "String.retval" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also you can use this...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pratclass1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner std= new Scanner(System.in);
String string1;
System.out.print("What is your name :");
string1= std.nextLine();

int count= 0;
int vowels=0;

char[] ar = new char[string1.length()];

for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    ar[i] = string1.charAt(i);
    if(ar[i] == 'a' || ar[i] == 'e' || ar[i] == 'i' || ar[i] == 'o'|| ar[i] == 'u') {
        vowels++;
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}

int total=vowels;
System.out.println();
System.out.println(total);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks you very much, The program did what you program to do. Im using it to study. Can you explain what a string.length is please? I would like to learn as much as I can.

Comment: string1.length() returns the character count of 'string1' with leading and trailing white spaces. so the char[] ar is initiated with that count. if user inputs some string value that holds leading and trailing white spaces, you can remove them by using 'string1.length().trim()'.

Comment: Thank you very much chetah. Is it okay to ask how long have you programmed?

Comment: nearly 8 months in java programming.

Comment: Thats awesome. Im looking for someone to really help me get better at CIS. I attend school at UAB as a CIS major, This is my first semester learning programming. So my question is are you willing to help/advise me? Is there a way to add you on this site? I want to have a better understanding with programming, I find it very hard. I have high respect for programmers! lol

Comment: i can help u. there is no way to add people here. if u can give me your email

Comment: danielsongandrews@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting your counter (vowels) with every iteration of the loop.  Don't set vowels=0 every time, let that number continue to grow with each vowel you find.

Once you've done that, you can remove all the random ++'s you've added to vowels in other spots, which is why your result always comes out to 3.

- vowels always comes out to 0 due to vowels=0 line
- totals = vowels++ --> totals = 0, vowels = 1
- total = (total + vowels++ + vowels) --> 3 = 0 + 1 (then make vowels 2) + 2

  ```
  int count= 0;
  int vowels=0;

  for(String retval: string1.split(""))
  {
      for(int i=0; i < retval.length(); i++)
      {
          char c= retval.charAt(i); 
          if(c== 'a' || c== 'e' || c== 'i' || c== 'o'|| c== 'u') 
          {
              vowels++;
          }
          else
          {
              count++;
          }
      }
  }

  System.out.println("Found " + vowels + " vowel(s) among " + (vowels + count) + " character(s).");
  ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    int count=0;
    int vowels=0;
    boolean isVowel = false;

    for(String retval: string1.split(""))
    {
        for(int i=0; i < retval.length(); i++)
        {
            char c= retval.charAt(i); 
            if(c== 'a' || c== 'e' || c== 'i' || c== 'o'|| c== 'u') 
            {
                isVowel = true;
                vowels++;
            }
            else
            {
                isVowel = false;
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(retval.substring(0,1) + retval.substring(1) + (isVowel ? 1 : 0) );
            }
    }
    System.out.println(vowels); //prints the number of vowels in the name
```

You only need a `boolean` to store whether or not the current `char` is a vowel. (isVowel ? 1 : 0) returns `1` when `isVowel==true` and `0` when `isVowel==false`. This is a ternary operator and is pretty handy.

Also, be careful when using `++` in an expression... look at the following code snippets for an example of why:

```
int total = 5;
int vowels = 2;

total = vowels++; //total = 2 and vowels = 3
```

if instead we wrote:

```
int total = 5;
int vowels = 2;

total = ++vowels; //total = 3 and vowels = 3
```

Recognize that `var++` returns the original value (and increments `var` by 1) while `++var` returns the incremented value (and increments `var` by 1)

Also, the `count` variable does nothing here, so unless there is more code that actually uses it, you can just delete it... `count` is going to return the number of non-vowels (this includes consonants, white space, symbols, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found the answer to your problem "counting vowels" in @Eric Lindauer answer.

But about "String.retval"  it is not "String.retval" but it is :

`for(String retval: string1.split(""))`

This is called **foreach** loop and means : for each string (you called it retval)in the big string (the whole name you enter ,you called it string1)do the following (the body of for loop)  .

If you enter "Daniel" the retval(s) will be :
D then a then i , e , l .

The output you see when you run your code is because you use **substring** method.

When you say  :  `retval.substring(0,1)`   it means "give me the substring in retval which begins from index 0 to 1"

And when you say :  `retval.substring(1)`    it means "give me the substring in retval which begins from index  1 to the end of string"

So when retval is "D" :retval.substring(0,1)= D 
... retval.substring(1)= nothing because the string length is one
 ... vowels = 0/1 (0 when it's not vowel and 1 when it is..it's alawys 1 because you make it zero after each loop)

And so `(retval.substring(0,1) + retval.substring(1) + vowels)`=D0

Comment: Thank you so so much! Im still learning to program, so (retval) was just the name of the  string I was using?

Comment: Exactly :) it was only a variable name @DanielAndrews

Comment: How long have you been programming? @Ghntek

Answer (score 0):

```
static final String NAME_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z]{2,}((-|\\s)[a-zA-Z]{2,})*$"; // https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D((-%7C%5Cs)%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D)*%24
static final String VOWELS = "aeiou";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = getName(sc);
    int vowelCount = getVowelCount(name);
    int consonantCount = name.replace(" ", "").replace("-", "").length() - vowelCount;
    System.out.printf("Vowels: %d\nConsonants: %d\n", vowelCount, consonantCount);
}

public static String getName(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.print("Type your name: ");
    String result = sc.nextLine();
    if (result.matches(NAME_PATTERN)) {
        return result;
    }
    System.out.println("Your input contains invalid characters. Try again please.");
    return getName(sc);
}

public static int getVowelCount(String name) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char letter : name.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (VOWELS.indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```